# Adding an itemid on the Tag component page

Tags: component, joomla-3.3.x, menu-item, tags

I just migrated my bilingual website to joomla 3.3.1 and I am discovering the tag feature, which is awesome! When I click on a tag displayed near the title of an article I am redirected to a page listing all the article with this tag. So far so good. But the problem is that there isn't any menu displayed on that component/tags page!

So I have been looking for a way to attach an itemid to a specific component page, but I didn't come close to a solution.

You can see what I mean [here](http://www.rscmovement.org/fr/component/tags/tag/3-politique)

Comment: Are you sure you have the menu module assigned to all pages?

Comment: Thanks @Lodder! This does solve the issue, but it won't work because one of my menu item redirects to a part of the website where the menu-item is not the same. SO I have the menu module A and B and all the A menu item redirects toward pages with the A menu, except the menu item A-5 with redirects toward a page with the menu module B. And same thing for the menu B. Menaing that can't choose the option "assigned to all pages". Is there a way to assigned an itemid to a component page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like there is no menu item for the tag component. Then you get something like this `/index.php/component/tags/tag/3-yellow` as your URL.

Try adding a menu item for example of the type `Tags » Compact list of tagged items`.

If you don't want this menu item visible, you can add it to a new menu. If you don't link this menu to a module, it will never show up on the site. But it will still be used for the SEF URLs. This way you can create nice URLs and even customise the view.

Comment: Thanks Bakual, this is the solution! You're right when I click on a tag I'm redirected to an address like component/tags/tag/science. So I did as you say, I created a new menu, added a new menu item (type tagged items), added the tag I want and assigned the menu module to this menu item... and voila! I preferred to choose tagged items rather than Compact list of tagged items because I prefer to get the intro text. The only downside is that I need to create one menu item per tag which is a lot of work. But anyway this is a better solution than the one selecting "on all pages" so thanks so much!