# How can I add modules to the tag search component page without adding menus for each tag item?

Tags: joomla-3.4, module, tags

UPDATE:
Because this is going to a client I am looking for a solution that does not involve creating new menu items for each new tag that is added.

I have a blog that includes tags. The tags are displayed next to the blog articles but once I click on a tag to view the articles associated with that tag (tag search) I'm not able to place a module on that page. My current solution, which isn't ideal, is to place the module that I want to display on the page to "on all pages except those selected". Are there any other solutions to this problem?

I have attached a couple images. You'll on the "Blog page" the tags to the right of the screen are a module. In the "Tag Search" page you'll see the module isn't there. I do have a menu item for the "Tag Search" page.

[image: tag search page]
[image: blog page]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an itemid on the Tag component page](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/adding-an-itemid-on-the-tag-component-page)

Comment: Hello @Heather and welcome to JSE. This questions has been asked before. Take a look at post http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/adding-an-itemid-on-the-tag-component-page

Comment: I did see that question but the issue is I would have to add a new menu item for each time a new tag is added. Because this is going to a client I will not have control over that piece once it is handed off to them. So not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation for Nonumber's Advanced Module Manager](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager#assignment-options) seems to suggest that you could assign modules to tags using that extension. I believe the tags feature comes with the free version. Please note that I have not investigated this feature, so there is a good chance that it works differently to how I've described.

Comment: I have used NN Advanced Module Manager for tags recently, and it also assumes that you add specific tag/tags, replicating feature to create menu items for every tag, but avoiding it. From what OP asked that is not something wanted. I still havent found real solution of creating menu itemid for ALL tags at once. Now, I'm really interested...

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that to use my solution you would need to create menu items for each of the tags? If yes, it would be best to give me a -1.

Comment: I didn't say that NN AMM solution requires one to create menu item for every tag, but REQUIRES to ADD EVERY TAG in module options, hence creating same or similar unwanted user experience, as OP clearly stated in her update.

Comment: sure man... :-)